# Rails/ruby make new hash

Tags: ruby-on-rails, arrays, ruby, hash

I have an array of arrays

```
arr = [ 
['category','subcat','detail'],['category1','subcat1','detail1']
]
```

I want to make a hash from it `{'category'=>'category','subcat'=>'subcat','detail'=>'detail'}...,other hashes from array`

```
hash={}
```

what i'm doing it's

```
arr.each{|el|
hash['category'] = el[0];
hash['subcat'] = el[1];
hash['detail'] = h[2];
}
```

but it returns only last element

`hash=>{category:'category1',subcat:'subcat1',detail:'detail1'}`

> when i do it with existing hash keys it works perfectly,but when i try to set new key -doesn't work

How to fix it?

Comment: Please fix your example code, it doesn't work. (BTW, `:category` is not equivalent to `"category"`)

Comment: Will there always be exactly two sub-arrays in `arr`?

Comment: @Jordan,  there could be a lot of arrays

Comment: Please edit your question to include an example of "a lot of arrays" and the expected output.

Comment: The problem is you keep overwriting the hash's keys with the succeeding array. A hash only has unique keys. The [documentation](http://ruby-doc.org/core-2.3.1/Hash.html) is clear about this: `A Hash is a dictionary-like collection of unique keys and their values.`

Comment: What is `h` in `hash['detail'] = h[2];`?

Comment: Spoiler tags? Seriously?

Answer (score 2):

Hashes can only have unique keys, duplicates aren't allowed. When you insert a duplicate you overwrite any previously existing key with the same name:

Meditate on this:

```
foo = {} # => {}
foo['a'] = 1
foo # => {"a"=>1}
```

`foo` now is a hash of a single key/value pair. If I try to add another element with the same key I only overwrite the previous value, I don't add another key/value pair:

```
foo['a'] = 2
foo # => {"a"=>2}
```

This is essentially what you're doing with:

```
arr.each{|el|
  hash['category'] = el[0];
  hash['subcat'] = el[1];
  hash['detail'] = h[2];
}
```

To make your code work you'll need to find different names for the keys for each iteration through the loop.

I can add a different key/value though:

```
foo['b'] = 3
foo # => {"a"=>2, "b"=>3}
```

See [the documentation](http://ruby-doc.org/core-2.3.1/Hash.html) or any Ruby hash tutorial for more information.

Answer (score 1):

You can use [Array#transpose](http://ruby-doc.org/core-2.3.1/Array.html#method-i-transpose) in combination w/ [Array#to_h](http://ruby-doc.org/core-2.3.1/Array.html#method-i-to_h). If you don't care if the keys of the hash are strings then you can simply do:

```
arr.transpose.to_h # => {"category"=>"category1", "subcat"=>"subcat1", "detail"=>"detail1"}
```

If you need the keys to be symbols then you'll need to do a little more work:

```
arr.transpose.to_h.inject({}){|hash, (k,v)| hash[k.to_sym] = v; hash }
```